# Use Vuejs blueprint within JHipster JDL

Tags: jhipster

I would like to now whether we could use vuejs blueprint within a JDL file within the `app` Section ?

Thx

Comment: I don't see any place to put a blueprint inside the JDL app section. This would be a nice feature like the way we can do it in the .yo-rc file. (https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/applications)

Comment: I did find this bug request dealing with this. They say it is working but I'm not sure how to get it done. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8610